# Symfony type:annotation won't include subdirectories

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create project with few controllers in different subfolders of "controller" directory.

my routing.yml config:

```
app:
resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
type:     annotation
```

Official Symfony best practice guide has information, that This configuration will load annotations from any controller stored inside the src/AppBundle/Controller/ directory and even from its subdirectories.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html

But when i'm trying to open page, that linked to subfolder controller, i have following error:

```
Class AppBundle\Controller\FirtreeShopMapController does not exist in 
/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from
 "/app/config/routing.yml").
```

my subdirectory controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FirtreeShopMapController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/firtreeShopMap", name="firtreeShopMap")
     */

    public function showFirtreeShopMapAction(Request $request)
    {
        $renderData = array();
        return $this->render('plugins/firtreeShopMap/index.html.twig', $renderData);
    }
}
```

My Controller directory structure:

```
Controller/
     ├─ DefaultController.php
     ├─ FirtreeShopMap/
     │  ├─ FirtreeShopMapController.php
```

So what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Start by using the correct namespace so the autoloader can find your class: namespace AppBundle\Controller\FirtreeShopMap;

Comment: Sorry, what is incorrect now?

Comment: oh!!! I should edit namespace in FirtreeShopMapController.php. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, @Cerad is correct.
Change the namespace line like so:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\FirtreeShopMap;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FirtreeShopMapController extends Controller
{
```

I think that's all you need to change.